# Not able to connect AWS MSK connect cluster to MSK cluster

Tags: aws-msk

I am unable to use my msk cluster when creating the connect app using aws msk connect cluster. I get error

```
You must choose an authentication method from your selected cluster.
```

I have enabled IAM based authentication on the cluster along with sasl

[image]

But when creating the msk connect plugin i am not able to select the auth method the filed is disabled as shown below. Does any one have success in using msk-connect-cluster
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because of mismatched version, msk conenct cluster needs 2.7.1 as minimum kafka version and the current instance of MSK clister which we were running was 2.7.0. Once after upgrade we were able to connect msk-connect cluster to msk cluster.

And the other issue we had is that our MSK cluster doesnt had any outbound rules, but MSK connect uses same SG as MSK cluster so need to add outbound rules on port `9098`